# CSV Class reader not getting actual image

Tags: python, csv, pytorch

I have a CSV file reader which reads a csv file with one column and obtains data about the image such as its label. After much debugging I have found my all data about the image is read but I'm missing the actual get image part, so currently, cv2 shows the input as a black box.

Im not sure what to do to achieve this, and need some assistance

My CSV Reader Below

```
def __init__(self, csvPath, imageHeight, imageWidth, transform = None):
    """
    Arguments:
        A CSV File Path
        Path to Image Foldr
        Extension of Images
        PIL Transforms
    """
    self.dataFromCSV = pD.read_csv(csvPath)
    self.dataLabels = nP.asarray(self.dataFromCSV.iloc[:, 0])
    self.imageHeight = imageHeight
    self.imageWidth = imageWidth
    self.transform = transform

def __getitem__(self, index):
    singleImageLabel = self.dataLabels[index]
    imagePath = singleImageLabel.split(";")[0]
    print ('Path: ' + str(imagePath))
    originalImage = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    cv2.imshow('IMAGE', originalImage)

    # Create an Empty Numpy Array to Fill
    imageAsNumpy = nP.ones((32, 32), dtype = 'uint8')

    # Fill the Numpy Array with Data from Pandas DF
    for i in range(1):
        rowPosition = (i-1) // self.imageHeight
        columnPosition = (i-1) % self.imageWidth
        indexFirst = self.dataFromCSV.iloc[index][i].split(";")[3]
        indexLast = self.dataFromCSV.iloc[index][i].split(";")[6]
        imageAsNumpy[rowPosition][columnPosition] = indexFirst + indexLast
        print ('LABEL: ' + str(singleImageLabel))
        cv2.imshow('INPUT',imageAsNumpy)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Convert Image from Numpy Array to PIL Image, Mode 'L' is for Grayscale
    imageAsImage = Image.fromarray(imageAsNumpy)
    imageAsImage = imageAsImage.convert('1')

    # Transform Image to Tensor
    if self.transform is not None:
        imageAsTensor = self.transform(imageAsImage)

    # Transform Label to Tensor
    labelAsLabel = int(singleImageLabel.split(";")[7])
    labelAsTensor = torch.from_numpy(nP.array(labelAsLabel))
    # print ('Target: ' + str(labelAsTensor))

    # Return Image & the Label
    return (imageAsTensor, labelAsLabel)

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.dataFromCSV.index)
```